# Playing vimeo video from specified time using iframe in samsung smart TV

Tags: html, webkit, samsung-smart-tv

Im trying to play vimeo video in samsung smart TV app from specified time using iframe.Im just appending the video url with **?#t=0m50s**.This works fine in browser like chrome and safari which support webkit, but in smart TV it starts from beginning.

`<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/86874445?autoplay=1?#t=0m50s" width="900" height="460" frameborder="0" ></iframe>`

It is given that samsung smart TV has also started using webkit browser engine and hence supports HTML5.If that is the case it should work.where I am going wrong..